# Keyboard overlaps content in Xamarin.Forms app on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]

I tried all solution to resolving keyboard overlapping issue.

1. set flag inside the view.

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

2. also tried with focused event but focused event is not firing. but nothing is working at all.

   ```
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadTabView BackgroundColor="{StaticResource 24dp}" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" IsContentSwipingEnabled="False"
                                              PropertyChanged="RadTabView_PropertyChanged">
                    <telerikPrimitives:RadTabView.Header>
                        <telerikPrimitives:TabViewHeader IsScrollable="True" ItemSpacing="40" Margin="10,0,10,0" Padding="0,10,0,10">
                        </telerikPrimitives:TabViewHeader>
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadTabView.Header>
                    <telerikPrimitives:RadTabView.Items>
                        <telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem>
                            <telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem.Header>
                                <telerikPrimitives:TabViewHeaderItem Text="DOC TYPE" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
                                </telerikPrimitives:TabViewHeaderItem>
                            </telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem.Header>
                            <telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem.Content>

                                    <StackLayout >

                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource 02dp}" Padding="10" Margin="10,5,10,10" BorderColor="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                                     <Grid>

                                            <commonviews:MyEntry  x:Name="txttrailerId"  IsEnabled="{Binding ShowEditableCommands}" Grid.Row="3" Label="Trailer ID" TextValue="{Binding TlmDoc.TrailerId, Mode=TwoWay}">


                                            </commonviews:TrackemEntry>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>
                                    </StackLayout>

                            </telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem.Content>
                        </telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem>
                        <telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem>

                        </telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem>
                        <telerikPrimitives:TabViewItem>

            </StackLayout>

                 </StackLayout>

                 </ScrollView>
   ```

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    try
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        txttrailerId.PropertyChanged += TxttrailerId_PropertyChanged;
        txttrailerId.Focused += TxttrailerId_Focused;
        txttrailerId.Unfocused += TxttrailerId_Unfocused; ;

        //...
    }

    private void TxttrailerId_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        Content.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, 0, Content.Bounds.Width, Content.Bounds.Height));
    }

    private void TxttrailerId_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        Content.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, -270, Content.Bounds.Width, Content.Bounds.Height));
    }
}
```

can someone help with me? what is wrong here. Thanks in advance. I updated the question.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the app to show what the keyboard is overlapping? so we can see what you see.

Comment: Can you show your XAML (or at least the relevant parts of it incl. the root and the layout)?

Comment: yes, i updated, @ewerspej

Answer (score 3):

Just specify the Android WindowSoftInputModeAdjust earlier in the lifetime of the app. I would recommend setting it in App.xaml Application tag:

```xml
<Application
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">

    ...

</Application>
```